# Take JSONAPI schema from model

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-restplus

In my Rest application I want to return `json` like `JSONAPI` format, but I need to create Schema class for it and create every field again that are already there in my `model`. So instead of creating every field in schema class can I not take it from `DB Model`..
below is my model class

```
class Author(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer)
  name = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

I am defining Schema like below.

```
class AuthorSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str()
    metadata = fields.Meta()

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'people'
        strict = True
```

So here, `id` and `name` I have defined it twice. so is there any option in `marshmallow-jsonapi` to assign model name in schema class so it can take all fields from `model`
Note: I am using `marshmallow-jsonapi`for it, I have tried `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` , it has that option but it not return `json` in `JSONAPI` format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flask-marshmallow`'s `ModelSchema` and `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` in combination with `marshmallow-jsonapi` with the caveat that you have to subclass not only the `Schema` classes but also the `SchemaOpts` classes, like this:

```
# ...
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow_jsonapi import Schema, SchemaOpts
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchemaOpts


# ...

ma = Marshmallow(app)

# ...

class JSONAPIModelSchemaOpts(ModelSchemaOpts, SchemaOpts):
    pass


class AuthorSchema(ma.ModelSchema, Schema):
    OPTIONS_CLASS = JSONAPIModelSchemaOpts

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'people'
        strict = True
        model = Author

# ...
foo = AuthorSchema()
bar = foo.dump(query_results).data # This will be in JSONAPI format including every field in the model
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,  now whenever I call  'foo.load(query_results)', it  calls function from modelschema and ask for database session. is there any way to call load from Schema ?

Comment: Are you running this outside of a request?